# GetType() with "simple" typenames

Tags: c#, types, casting

I am trying to read an xml-file where beyond other parameters the type of a field can be given. Example:

```
<elements>
   <element>
      <elementType>int</elementType>
   <element> 
      <elementType>string</elementType>
   </element>
<elements>
```

Now I want to get the type by using type.GetType(value) where value is "int" or "string" for example. It works with "System.String" or "System.Int32" for example but I do not want the users to enter the exact type. Can this be done in an elegant way (no switch-case-nonsene)?

Comment: No. They are just C# compiler's aliases.

Comment: Why would users enter a type name?

Comment: @Amy inner platform effect. OP seems to be creating something like a scripting or rule engine. If the business requires and the users agree; why not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you need to have some switch-case-"nonsense" or a dictionary that does the mapping for you.

Those are not .NET types, those are the C# keywords that map to .NET types.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to do this.  The full list of type aliases can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).  You can easily include a dictionary of types to alias string names in your solution.  Here is the current list:

- bool
  : System.Boolean
- byte
  : System.Byte
- sbyte
  : System.SByte
- char
  : System.Char
- decimal
  : System.Decimal
- double
  : System.Double
- float
  : System.Single
- int
  : System.Int32
- uint
  : System.UInt32
- long
  : System.Int64
- ulong
  : System.UInt64
- object
  : System.Object
- short
  : System.Int16
- ushort
  : System.UInt16
- string
  : System.String